# Just started learning type script. I have written simple program below. Instead of "Hi shri vishnu" as output I'm getting Hi ${fstname} ${lstname}

Tags: typescript

```
let found: boolean = true;
let grade: number = 88.9;
let fstname: String = 'shri';
let lstname: String = 'vishnu';

console.log(found);
console.log(grade);
console.log('Hi ${fstname} ${lstname}');
```

can anyone help why i am getting like this. The color of this part ${fstname} ${lstname} should actually be blue. but it is orange(same as contents in inverted commas[this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJW44.png))

Comment: If you want to use [template literal types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) then you need to use backticks `\`` and not single quotes `'`.  This feels like a typo-ish question

Comment: The backtick can be found at the top left of a qwerty keyboard. Single quote is at the middle right.